# How to load row major data from text file in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can row-major text data files be loaded with numpy?

The `loadtxt(..)` function loads column-major, i.e. the data lies in rows below names in the first row, how can I load data where the names are in the 1st column and data in subsequent columns?

Row major:

```
field 1: d1, d2, d3, ...
field 2: d1, d2, d3, ...
field n: ...
```

Comment: Would'nt that be ohk if you just transpose after loading column major?

Comment: Is this an actual example of the data with all the `---` and `|` characters?

Comment: @Dark This would work in theory, but is unfortunately not supported by `loadtxt(...)` or any other loader I can find in numpy.

Comment: @kazemakase I've edited the question to remove them

Comment: The `skiprows` argument might help but I guess the different delimiters between row names (`:`) and items (`,`) will be a problem...

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `unpack=True` does this.

> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be unpacked using x, y, z = loadtxt(...). When used with a structured data-type, arrays are returned for each field. Default is False.

This does not require you to actually unpack, if you only need a transpose; `arr = np.loadtxt(file, unpack=False)` returns one transposed array,

Example: the default behavior

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> file = StringIO("0 1 2\n3 4 5")
>>> np.loadtxt(file)
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])
```

Compared to `unpack=True`

```
>>> file = StringIO("0 1 2\n3 4 5")
>>> np.loadtxt(file, unpack=True)
array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  5.]])
```

---

Also, it's possible that your use case would be better served by [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and working with the data as a DataFrame.